Python Export not working as expected in QGIS Model Designer
I have created a snapping model using the model designer in QGIS 3.34.9. My problem is when I export this model as a Python file, it gives me the same output as the input GeoJSON.
The lines are exploded and further, My model is supposed to snap lines based on a threshold i.e. in step 1 it takes 2 lines, S1 (input, to be snapped), R1 (reference for snap) and snapping takes place with a value of 0.5 meter.
Further, It creates a threshold of 1 meters (this is being done to discard the lines that are already snapped in the previous snap tolerance) for which I am using the "Extract by expression" tool and the following is the expression:
overlay_nearest(@Snap1_OUTPUT, max_distance:= 1)

.
Further, the lines that are 'non-matching' in this go into 2nd iteration with a higher threshold of 1 meter and so on.

While using the model from the model builder is giving the correct output, the Python extract does not give the correct output. What am I missing?
Python Script:
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : Snap_Method3
Group : 
With QGIS : 33409
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem
import processing


class Snap_method3(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('core_layer', 'Core Layer', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('reference_layer', 'Reference Layer', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('AdditionalGeometryIdentified', 'Additional Geometry Identified', optional=True, type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=False, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Snap_output', 'Snap_output', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue='TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(16, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Core_Reproject
        alg_params = {
            'CONVERT_CURVED_GEOMETRIES': False,
            'INPUT': parameters['core_layer'],
            'OPERATION': '',
            'TARGET_CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857'),
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Core_reproject'] = processing.run('native:reprojectlayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Core_Explode
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['Core_reproject']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Core_explode'] = processing.run('native:explodelines', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Reference_Reproject
        alg_params = {
            'CONVERT_CURVED_GEOMETRIES': False,
            'INPUT': parameters['reference_layer'],
            'OPERATION': '',
            'TARGET_CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857'),
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Reference_reproject'] = processing.run('native:reprojectlayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Reference Explode lines
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['Reference_reproject']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ReferenceExplodeLines'] = processing.run('native:explodelines', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract_1
        alg_params = {
            'EXPRESSION': 'overlay_nearest(  @Create_spatial_index_OUTPUT , max_distance:= 0.5)',
            'INPUT': outputs['ReferenceExplodeLines']['OUTPUT'],
            'FAIL_OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Extract_1'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(5)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract_2
        alg_params = {
            'EXPRESSION': 'overlay_nearest( @Snap1_OUTPUT , max_distance:= 1)',
            'INPUT': outputs['Extract_1']['FAIL_OUTPUT'],
            'FAIL_OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Extract_2'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(6)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract_3
        alg_params = {
            'EXPRESSION': 'overlay_nearest( @Snap2_OUTPUT , max_distance:= 2.5)',
            'INPUT': outputs['Extract_2']['FAIL_OUTPUT'],
            'FAIL_OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Extract_3'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(7)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Snap1
        alg_params = {
            'BEHAVIOR': 2,  # Prefer aligning nodes, don't insert new vertices
            'INPUT': outputs['Core_explode']['OUTPUT'],
            'REFERENCE_LAYER': outputs['Extract_1']['OUTPUT'],
            'TOLERANCE': 0.55,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Snap1'] = processing.run('native:snapgeometries', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(8)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract_4
        alg_params = {
            'EXPRESSION': 'overlay_nearest( @Snap3_OUTPUT , max_distance:= 5)',
            'INPUT': outputs['Extract_3']['FAIL_OUTPUT'],
            'FAIL_OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Extract_4'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(9)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract_5
        alg_params = {
            'EXPRESSION': 'overlay_nearest( @Snap4_OUTPUT , max_distance:= 10)',
            'INPUT': outputs['Extract_4']['FAIL_OUTPUT'],
            'FAIL_OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Extract_5'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(10)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract_6
        alg_params = {
            'EXPRESSION': 'overlay_nearest( @Snap5_OUTPUT , max_distance:= 12.5)',
            'INPUT': outputs['Extract_5']['FAIL_OUTPUT'],
            'FAIL_OUTPUT': parameters['AdditionalGeometryIdentified'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Extract_6'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['AdditionalGeometryIdentified'] = outputs['Extract_6']['FAIL_OUTPUT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(11)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Snap2
        alg_params = {
            'BEHAVIOR': 2,  # Prefer aligning nodes, don't insert new vertices
            'INPUT': outputs['Snap1']['OUTPUT'],
            'REFERENCE_LAYER': outputs['Extract_2']['OUTPUT'],
            'TOLERANCE': 1.05,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Snap2'] = processing.run('native:snapgeometries', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(12)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Snap3
        alg_params = {
            'BEHAVIOR': 2,  # Prefer aligning nodes, don't insert new vertices
            'INPUT': outputs['Snap2']['OUTPUT'],
            'REFERENCE_LAYER': outputs['Extract_3']['OUTPUT'],
            'TOLERANCE': 2.55,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Snap3'] = processing.run('native:snapgeometries', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(13)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Snap4
        alg_params = {
            'BEHAVIOR': 2,  # Prefer aligning nodes, don't insert new vertices
            'INPUT': outputs['Snap3']['OUTPUT'],
            'REFERENCE_LAYER': outputs['Extract_4']['OUTPUT'],
            'TOLERANCE': 5.05,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Snap4'] = processing.run('native:snapgeometries', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(14)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Snap5
        alg_params = {
            'BEHAVIOR': 2,  # Prefer aligning nodes, don't insert new vertices
            'INPUT': outputs['Snap4']['OUTPUT'],
            'REFERENCE_LAYER': outputs['Extract_5']['OUTPUT'],
            'TOLERANCE': 10.05,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Snap5'] = processing.run('native:snapgeometries', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(15)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Snap6
        alg_params = {
            'BEHAVIOR': 2,  # Prefer aligning nodes, don't insert new vertices
            'INPUT': outputs['Snap5']['OUTPUT'],
            'REFERENCE_LAYER': outputs['Extract_6']['OUTPUT'],
            'TOLERANCE': 12.55,
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Snap_output']
        }
        outputs['Snap6'] = processing.run('native:snapgeometries', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Snap_output'] = outputs['Snap6']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'Snap_Method3'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'Snap_Method3'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Snap_method3()



Can you provide some test data and the full model script?

@Matt I have added the full script in question and here's the test data (core is supposed to be snapped based on the reference 'ref' data)
https://github.com/dante3112/Zoomify_satellite/tree/main/test_region
